# Import a module one step back of the path

Tags: python, import, module

Hi I have the following file structure

[image: Folder Structure Image]

Main and package directories are on the same level

I want to import `test.py` in the `app.py`. Kindly help me how can we import this without using sys path

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is "Backend" a package? (And if so, is it the main package, and are Main and package subpackages?)

Comment: Backend is just an folder containing two subpackages Main and package respectively

Comment: /questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time